# open and edit a file takes effect on another file as well

Tags: linux, bash, perl, shell, awk

I want to create a file that when opened another .txt file opens too.
or when edited another .txt file will be edited, or any other action that is performed on
it will be performed on  that file too.

Is there any way to simply do this with a linux command ? Note that I don't want to copy or move the file.

Comment: don't you just want a symbolic link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a symlink:

```
ln -s original newlink
```

Now, `newlink` will refer to `original` and each can be treated mostly like a regular file.